# Recursive sequence in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, recursion, sequence

I want to write a function which has 5 inputs :

[image]

which outputs

[image] :

Problem seems very simple for me, however I'm dealing with error :

```
Function Sequence(x_0 As Double, x_1 As Double, a As Double, b As Double, n As Double) As Double
    If n = 0 Then
        x_0
    ElseIf n = 1 Then
        x_1
    Else
        a * Sequence(x_0, x_1, a, b, n-1) + b * Sequence(x_0, x_1, a, b, n-2)
    End If
End Function
```

And If I want to use my function :

```
Sequence(1;1;1;1;1)
```

I see error :

[image]

Do you hany idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your error, but In Excel O365, `SEQUENCE` is a built-in function. Perhaps you should consider a different name for your UDF, depending on your intended audience and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In VBA, the function to call parameters must be separated by comma. Like a UDF function you can call it from sheet using the list separator according to regional settings ["=Sequence(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) or Sequence(1; 1; 1; 1; 1)];
2. If a called function returns something, the way you call it should be in a way to deal with the returned value:

```
Debug.Print Sequence(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Then, try playing with the function parameters.

3. When there are some conditional function outputs, your function must be configured to return:

```
Function Sequence(x_0 As Double, x_1 As Double, a As Double, b As Double, n As Double) As Double
    If n = 0 Then
        Sequence = x_0
    ElseIf n = 1 Then
        Sequence = x_1
    Else
        Sequence = a * Sequence(x_0, x_1, a, b, n - 1) + b * Sequence(x_0, x_1, a, b, n - 2)
    End If
End Function
```